# How to draw line a that goes from -Inf to Inf?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 JS scatter plot with zooming capabilities for which I pre-compute a Linear regression (OLS) and I can draw the trend line like this:

```
var objects = svg.append("svg")
    .classed("objects", true)
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]).nice();
var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]).nice();

objects.append("svg:line")
    .classed("trendline", true)
    .attr("x1", x(xMin))
    .attr("y1", y(lineIntercept + xMin*lineSlope))
    .attr("x2", x(xMax))
    .attr("y2", y(lineIntercept + xMax*lineSlope))
    .attr("stroke", colorVal)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);
```

this does what I want except that the line goes from `xMin` to `xMax` and I'd like it to go from -Inf to Inf and this becomes evident when the user Zooms out, how can I do that?

Comment: I mean when zooming out or panning the line never ends on either side. Yes I guess that's what it means.

Comment: I think a more reasonable approach would be to adjust xMin/xMax as you zoom.

Comment: Oh good idea .. didn't think about it ...

Comment: But then how to get the current domain ranges the zoom is currently in?

Comment: Well, you could start with a constant that is in a ratio with the zoom, so your xMin/xMax would be -400/400 at zoom level 1. Then, when zooming out (non-implementation specific) your zoom level is 2.5, your xMin/xMax would map to -1000/1000.

Comment: and so duplicating the functionality that scale and domain already offer ...

Comment: Not meant to duplicate `domain` functionality, but I see you've found your answer! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to  (as discussed in the Q comments) after every zoom find out the current domain position of the x axis ends (obtained calling `x.domain()`) and then update the line. The complete solution is as follows:

```
objects
    .selectAll(".trendline")
    .attr("x1", x(x.domain()[0]))
    .attr("y1", y(lineIntercept + x.domain()[0]*lineSlope))
    .attr("x2", x(x.domain()[1]))
    .attr("y2", y(lineIntercept + x.domain()[1]*lineSlope))
    .attr("stroke", colorVal)
    .attr("stroke-width", 2);
```

This gives the visual impression that the line goes from -Inf to Inf